# JGroups: Discovery num_discovery_runs is not working

Tags: java, jgroups

I have my own `Protocol[]` which looks like this

```
  Protocol[] prot_stack = {
                    new UDP(),
                    new PING()
                            .setValue("num_discovery_runs", 10)
                            .setValue("stagger_timeout", 1500)
                            .setValue("async_discovery", true)
                            .setValue("async_discovery_use_separate_thread_per_request", true)
                            .setValue("discovery_rsp_expiry_time", 5000),
                    new MERGE3(),
                    new FD_SOCK(),
                    new FD_ALL(),
                    new VERIFY_SUSPECT(),
                    new BARRIER(),
                    new NAKACK2(),
                    new UNICAST3(),
                    new STABLE(),
                    new GMS(),
                    new UFC(),
                    new MFC(),
                    new FRAG2()};
```

but for some reason if `num_discovery_runs` is set to 10, the discovery does not work anymore and it never responds anymore. When `num_discovery_run` is set to 3, it runs the discovery, but only once.

It does not run it three times. It just discovers after 3000ms that there is no Coordinator available and creates his own (which I want to prevent by having more discovery runs).

The current code looks like this

```
channel = new JChannel(prot_stack).setReceiver(this).addChannelListener(this);
channel.setDiscardOwnMessages(true);
channel.setName("RFID Cluster");
channel.connect("RFID Cluster");
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can I not change the amount of discovery runs higher than 3 (which does not even work anyway).

According to the [documentation](http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#Discovery) this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a bug!

I've created [1], fixed it and committed the change to `master`. You can try out the fix by creating a JAR from source (`ant jar` or `mvn package` will do the job), or wait for 4.1.5 to be release. This will take a couple of weeks.

Workaround: don't set `num_discovery_runs` to a value greater than `1`.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JGRP-2375

Comment: Thank you. Is there a mailing list I could join?

Comment: Yes, follow the link on jgroups.org